# Naming and Saving docx file using pandas list and python docx

Tags: python, pandas, docx

I use pandas to get list of employee names from excel sheet and want to create docx file for each name in cell as docx filename. I got 10 names and i need to create 10 docx file automatically.

Current effort: Learnt to read the names and create a docx file.

```
from docx import Document
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(open('test.xlsx','rb'))
print(df)
document = Document()
document.save('Name of the relevant cells.docx')
```

How to read through each cell value and pass it on to the file so as to create 10 docx file wit h relavant name.

Contents of test.xlsx

**Names**

Adam

Smith

John

Mark

Please help with alphanumeric also like Place_postalcode in case some future necessity occurs.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data in the `test.xlsx`? If the datatype is not a string, conversion to string would most likely be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to loop through the names in the df['Names'] and create a `Document` with the name

Test data:

[image]

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('test.xlsx','rb'))
for name in df.Names:
    document = Document()
    document.save(str(name)+'.docx')
```

Result:

[image]

Converting the name to string will handle both numeric and alpha-numeric file names. You can also have the file names with space.